# Web Service Custom Binding - sign SOAP header and message, but don't encrypt

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I am trying to figure out how to call a Java Web Service (blackbox) from .NET which expects each request to be signed with a certificate (which is no problem).

I don't get it. Whatever I try, it fails. After spending hours with researching and testing I think the right way should be to use a customBinding instead of a basicHttpBinding. What I want to achieve is to sign the header as well as the message body.

By using authentication mode **CertificateOverTransport** only the SOAP header is signed, not the body. By using authentication mode **MutualCertificate** everything is signed and encrypted.

Do I have any chance to disable the encryption of the whole message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.

Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <customBinding>
            <binding name="FFB">
              <context protectionLevel="Sign" />
              <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
              <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" includeTimestamp="true" />
              <httpsTransport />
            </binding>
          </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And additionally:

```
service.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However "context protectionLevel=Sign" and "...Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign" ought to be redundant => Some testing shows "context protectionLevel=Sign" has no effect and can be removed. I'd love to find out what to put in the binding to be able to remove instead the line of code that sets the ProtectionLevel to Sign, but no success up to now :-(

Comment: Sorry @jmd, you can't! See this very prominent note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : `Protection levels can be set only in code, not in configuration`